# The solutions of the heat equation from $0$ datum

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

Consider the initial value problem
$$ \partial_t u = \Delta u$$
$$ u(0,x) = 0$$
for the heat equation in $\mathbb R^n$, where $u: [0,T] \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a smooth solution up to the time $T$. Suppose there exists a large constant $N>0$ such that
$$
|u(t,x)| \le N\exp(N|x|^2t^{-1})
$$
for any $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $t\in (0,T]$.

Can we prove that $u(t,x)$ must be identically $0$?

Notice that if $|u(t,x)| \le N\exp(N|x|^2)$, then the question is true by Tychonoff's theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the classical Tychonoff's example, $$u(t,x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{g^{(k)}(t) x^{2k}}{(2k)!},$$ with $g(t) = e^{-1/t^\alpha}$ and $\alpha > 1$?

As discussed, for example, in [these lecture notes](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/yanb/847ch3.pdf), in this case $$|g^{(k)}(t)| \leqslant \frac{k!}{(\theta t)^k} e^{-1/(2 t^\alpha)} \tag{$\star$}$$ for some $\theta > 0$ (*edit: see below for a proof*), and hence
$$ |u(t, x)| \leqslant \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{k! x^{2k}}{(\theta t)^k(2k)!} e^{-1 / (2 t^\alpha)} \leqslant \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2 \theta t)^k k!} e^{-1 / (2 t^\alpha)} = e^{x^2/(2 \theta t)-1/(2t^\alpha)} \leqslant e^{x^2 / (2 \theta t)} . $$
If I am not mistaken, this (counter-)example implies a negative question to your answer.

---

*Edit:* For completeness, here is the proof of ($\star$). This is, of course, completely standard; I reworked it only to convince myself that there is no error in my answer.

The function $g(t) = e^{-1/t^\alpha}$ is holomorphic in the right complex half-plane. By Cauchy's formula (applied to the circle $\Gamma$ centred at $t$ with radius $\theta t$), we have
$$ g^{(k)}(t) = \frac{k!}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{g(z)}{(z - t)^{k + 1}} dz = \frac{k!}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{g(t + \theta t e^{i s})}{(\theta t e^{i s})^k} ds . $$
Therefore,
$$ |g^{(k)}(t)| \leqslant \frac{k!}{2\pi (\theta t)^k} \int_0^{2\pi} |g(t + \theta t e^{i s})| ds . $$
Choose $\theta > 0$ small enough, so that the image of the disk $D(1, \theta)$ under $z \mapsto z^{-\alpha}$ is contained in the half-plane $\Re z > \tfrac{1}{2}$. Since $|g(z)| = e^{-\Re z^{-\alpha}}$, we have $$|g(t + \theta t e^{i s})| = e^{-t^{-\alpha} \Re (1 + \theta e^{i s})^{-\alpha}} \leqslant e^{-t^{-\alpha} / 2} .$$
It follows that $|g^{(k)}(t)| \leqslant \frac{k!}{(\theta t)^k} e^{-1 / (2 t^\alpha)}$, as desired.

Comment: Kwasnicki For the Tychonoff argument to work,  you need $\alpha >1$. In fact, up to geometrical terms $g^{(k)}$ is bounded above by $k^{k(1+\frac{1}{\alpha})}$ and you have in the series a denominator as $k^{2k}$, so you need $1+\frac{1}{\alpha}<2$. A reference is https://doi.org/10.1017/S001309150000095X

Comment: @Bazin: Thanks for spotting the typo, and for the reference! Regarding the estimate of $g^{(k)}$, unfortunately I do not have time now to check the bound given in the lecture notes (which is left as a "good exercise").

Comment: @Kwasnicki the good exercise is to prove that your function $g$ belongs to the Gevrey class $G^{1+\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ (this is sharp). Checking the Faa di Bruno theorem is one way to get this, but complex analysis with Cauchy theorem would give you the same answer.

Comment: @Bazin: Thanks for the comment. I am not sure if I understand correctly, though: you seem to refer to uniform bounds for $g^{(k)}$, while here one needs an estimate that can deteriorate as $t \to 0^+$: a uniform bound for $t^k g^{(k)}(t)$. I believe both estimates follow from Faà di Bruno's formula, but, as said above, I did not attempt to check it. If you did, or if you can improve the answer in any other way, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: @Kwasnicki you do not need anything else than $\vert g^{(k)}\vert\le C^{k+1} k^{k(1+\frac{1}{\alpha })}$ with $\alpha >1$ for the Tychonoff example to work: you have applying the heat operator a telescoping series and the convergence follows from the estimate $\vert g^{(k)}\vert\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\lesssim  R^{2k}k^{k(-1+\frac{1}{\alpha})}$.

Comment: @Bazin: OK, I understand now: your comments aim at explaining what is needed to check that Tychonoff's example is a solution to the heat equation (as long as $\alpha > 1$), while mine were focused on how one gets the (slightly simpler) bound now tagged ($\star$). I should have been more careful and write "for Tychonoff's example to answer the original question" rather than "here" in my previous comment!